# How to Dismiss Menu when click View SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, menu

I want to dismiss my Menu when click somewhere in view . Now when i click product Image it goes product detail.How can I solve this problem . Basically I want to dismiss only Menu when I click somewhere in view.

[image]

```
 @State var selectedSort : String = ""
@State var isSelected : Bool = false
@Binding var sortClicked : Bool
@ObservedObject var productListViewModel = ProductListViewModel()
@State var sortListArray : [ProductListSortAndFilterList]
var function: () -> Void
@Binding var sortId : String

var body : some View {
    
    HStack(alignment: .center){
        
        Spacer()
        
        Menu {
            
            ForEach(sortListArray,id:\.id){ item in
                if item.id == "sort" {
                    
                    ForEach(item.sortList ?? [],id:\.id) { data in
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            selectedSort = data.name ?? ""
                            
                            sortId = (data.id ?? "")
                            
                            self.function()
                            
                            
                        }) {
                            
                            Text(data.name ?? "")
                                .tag(data.id)
                            
                            if selectedSort == data.name {
                                
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } label: {
            
            SortIcon()
            
        }
```

Comment: I don’t see any issue with above shared code, apart from Spacer() being used just after HStack with centre alignment., which is a bit odd.

Comment: It is default behavior of `Menu`. What you can do is disable the `NavigationLink` when `Menu` is open.

Comment: @egeeke I did same thing but how can I make NavigationLink enable again. Is there a way to know if Menu is closed ? otherwise I need to check 2 thing (isSort Selected and if user clicked View ) .